# php csv file renaming

Tags: php

I have a form with upload field i click the browse button and choose test1.csv.
I go to desktop and rename the file as test2.csv
Now my requirement is when i uploa di have to show javascript OR PHP error message that the file name is not available for upload.

Comment: (-1) What is your question exactly? Also, I don't understand your requirement. *When* should the script throw an error? What does it have to do with your client side renaming? Please add more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code should do what you ask:

http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/05/php-file-upload-and-download-script.html